# Android's per-application max heap size

Tags: android

Android has a heap size limit for each app. It could be 16M, 24M, 32M, etc.
My question is, will the size of the app itself is taken into account in the heap size limit?

For example, suppose the Android max heap size per-app is 16M. And my app is 10M bytes in size. Does it mean the OS will only leave the app 6M bytes heap after the app is running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your app is made of classes and drawable that will be loaded into memory at run time only when you use it. So for example let's say your app contains drawable that are for tablets, they are not loaded into the memory of a phone.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll have all 16M of heap.

Things that eat the heap are classes loaded in RAM, and objects created in RAM during the app session.